# Find the follow sets

Tags: code-golf, grammars

**The challenge below requires you to be familiar with formal parser theory.** If you don't know what the question is asking because you don't know what the terms mean, context-free grammars and first/follow sets are covered in a lot of university courses.

I can recommend [this Stanford course](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/), in particular handouts 08 and 09 (from page 7). I've extracted also extracted a [cheat sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPuvy.png) from these handouts  - *I recommend anyone attempting this challenge to read it*.

---

Write a program or function that given a context-free grammar finds the follow set of every nonterminal. Informally, the follow set of a nonterminal is a set of terminals and `$` (meaning end-of-input) that you can possibly find after that terminal in a valid sentence.

The input is given as a single printable ASCII string or array of printable ASCII lines. You may output the sets in any reasonable format, using `$` (either as literal output, or string inside a set, etc) to indicate the end of input. **You may assume that the input is always valid according to the format below.**

The context free grammar is given in a very simplified manner. Every line contains a single production. Every production is a space separated list of symbols. A terminal is a string of characters surrounded by apostrophes (e.g. `'**'`). For simplicity you may assume that terminals do not contain spaces, but it would be nice if your program allows it. A nonterminal may be any string not containing spaces or `$`. The empty production (normally indicated with ε) is simply a line containing only the left hand side nonterminal. The first line is the production defining the start symbol.

As an example, the following grammar:

S → aSa | bSb | ε

Will be given as:

```
S 'a' S 'a'
S 'b' S 'b'
S
```

---

Example input / outputs:

```
In:
S 'a' S 'a'
S 'b' S 'b'
S

Out:
S {'a', 'b', $}

In:
S A B C
A 'a'
A C 'b'
A
B C
B 'd' A
B
C 'e'
C 'f' 

Out:
S {$}
A {'d', 'e', 'f'}
B {'e', 'f'}
C {'b', 'e', 'f', $}

In:
Start Alice Bob
Alice Charlie 'a'
Alice
Bob Bob 'a' Alice Charlie
Bob '!!!'
Charlie 'b'
Charlie

Out:
Start {$}
Alice {'a', '!!!', 'b', $}
Bob {'a', $}
Charlie {'a', $}
```

---

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Assuming that people know what a context free grammar is seems fine, but I think it wouldn't hurt the challenge if you included the definition of a follow set right here instead of just linking to it.

Comment: This brings back some memories from "*Compiler Construction*" at university, where we had to solve lots of similar tasks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Perl, 257 bytes

Includes +4 for `-0p`

Give grammar on STDIN (without trailing spaces. Make sure to remove the extra space in the second example). Assumes non-terminal names only contain letters, digits and `_`. Uses `#` instead of `$` to indicate end of input. Can handle literals containing spaces

```
perl -M5.010 follow.pl
E T e
e '+' T e
e
T F t
t '*' F t
t
F '(' E ')'
F 'id'
^D
```

Outputs the follow sets as a list of `non-terminal literal` in no particular order. For the example above it outputs:

```
F ')'
F #
t ')'
t #
T ')'
T #
F '+'
t '+'
T '+'
F '*'
e ')'
e #
E ')'
E #
```

`follow.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -0n
s/'.*?'/~$&/eg;s% (?=(\w.*\n))%$_.=">$1"%reg;/\s/;$_.=">$` #\n";s%^((\w+)\K ?\S*).*%$s{$1}++||"\$a.=s/ $2\\b/$&/rg"%eemgr,s%^(\w+ ).*?(\w+)$%"\$a.=s/>$1/>$2 /rg"%eermg,$_.=$a,s%>.*\xd8\K .*%%g,s%.+\n%$&x!/\n$&/g%eg until$$_++;s/\xd8.*?\xd8/~$&/eg;say/>(\w+ \W\S*\n)/g
```

Works as shown, but replace `\xd8` and `\n` by their literal versions to get the claimed score.

It should be possible to improve this since converting the `first` sets to the `follow` sets is currently very awkward.

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 271 bytes

```py
def f(g):
 d={g[0][0]:{''}}
 q=[(i[1:],[])for i in g]
 for a,S in q:
  for i,A in enumerate(a):
   if A and"'"!=A[0]:
    if a[i+1:]and"'"==a[i+1][0]:d[A]={*d.get(A,[]),a[i+1],''}
    for j,*k in g:
     if j==A and(j,k)not in S:q+=[(a[:i]+k+a[i+1:],S+[(j,k)])]
 return d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNT@MwED2vf8U0l3EaC20pBxQpB7eCA0hcyi0brVziGPfDab3mgCp@e9fjBHaRQLKsN/Nm3htbc3gNz72bXx/8@dzqDjpu8pJBW51M/bOJpzwhvr0xOFY1t/WsbETd5F3vwYJ1YBoGFCixovAYW1NshaRYu5e99iporkgVwHYgQbk2w2xSSZKnLKVVbYuoPnBVlcLk39ayqU7T9sLowCW5i4EUcbDUTYYbMd2mgQZBUtxUVfLiG7HNXR@IXpXHIj5E1aVtim0xmopVUaeqJo/v8Tq8eAft2cyggizL2ApQIaSb8DrhNWFGtLn8qJOwgCWTqVLCMlVJRrkFYIsQMYtZjXR3OPQzM38XCMoHkDv7pGHRr9mAls/K76weRCnDIkd8GutTTWJwMplEg/eu9Qce3a5Gtxt4hDt2B1jggNgj3MI9uwec4oDYLSBHuAHMkbBtcRChXQn9b@PVfq98Wpof48fV9uLPYWcD/7cmnd0F7flD77QAM9L4y2EeP5wdvHWBd/x/vVme518Sl98R8@@Iq0ic/wI)

Comment: The solution is not complete yet. It's missing the end-of-input / `$` symbol output.